# Adding Parameters to a Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, k2

I am new to `K2`and `SQL Server`.

I want to add a parameter to a stored procedure, which will be later tied to a `K2` smart object for the respective views and forms.

Currently it takes in 1 parameter, `lang`, which is an input from a label from the `K2` Smartform View.

I added a label `labelHideInactiveCompany` on the same view, and I would like to pass that value into my Stored Procedure but I don't know how to do it.

I am told that the first thing I need to change is the stored procedure, and then updating the `smart object`.

May I know what are the steps I should be take? Thank you.

Below is my query:

```
USE [K2_Database]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [Config].[usp_ListBusinessUnit] 
@lang varchar(2) = null
as

SELECT EntityId
      ,EntityCode
      ,EntityName
      ,CO.OrganizationDesc
      ,EntityAbbreviation
      ,PBU.ParentBusinessUnitName
      ,EntityAttribute 
      ,EntityOwnedCompany
      ,EntityPrincipal
      ,EntityAccountingProgram 
      ,EntityCurrency
      ,EntityCurrenyExchRate 
      ,BU.CountryRegion
      ,EntityNCOwnedIndustry
      ,BU.IsActive 
      ,BU.CreatedBy 
      ,CreateOn 
      ,BU.ModifiedBy
      ,BU.ModifiedOn 
      ,BU.Lang AS LangAbbr
  FROM Config.BusinessUnit BU
  LEFT JOIN Config.Organization CO on BU.OrganizationId = CO.OrganizationId
  LEFT JOIN Config.ParentBusinessUnit PBU on BU.ParentBusinessUnitId = PBU.ParentBusinessUnitId 
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN @lang = 'cn' THEN BU.Lang END,
           CASE WHEN @lang = 'en' THEN BU.Lang END DESC, 
           EntityName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want this parameter and this WHERE clause:

```
ALTER procedure [Config].[usp_ListBusinessUnit] 
@lang varchar(2) = null, 
@hideInactiveCompany bit = 0 -- Add this parameter!
as

SELECT EntityId
      ,EntityCode
      ,EntityName
      ,CO.OrganizationDesc
      ,EntityAbbreviation
      ,PBU.ParentBusinessUnitName
      ,EntityAttribute 
      ,EntityOwnedCompany
      ,EntityPrincipal
      ,EntityAccountingProgram 
      ,EntityCurrency
      ,EntityCurrenyExchRate 
      ,BU.CountryRegion
      ,EntityNCOwnedIndustry
      ,BU.IsActive 
      ,BU.CreatedBy 
      ,CreateOn 
      ,BU.ModifiedBy
      ,BU.ModifiedOn 
      ,BU.Lang AS LangAbbr
  FROM Config.BusinessUnit BU
  LEFT JOIN Config.Organization CO on BU.OrganizationId = CO.OrganizationId
  LEFT JOIN Config.ParentBusinessUnit PBU on BU.ParentBusinessUnitId = PBU.ParentBusinessUnitId 
  WHERE (@hideInactiveCompany = 0 OR BU.IsActive = 1) -- Use the parameter!
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN @lang = 'cn' THEN BU.Lang END,
           CASE WHEN @lang = 'en' THEN BU.Lang END DESC, 
           EntityName
```

Comment: I met the same error with Jon P's approach, `Incorrect syntax near '@hideInactiveCompany'.`. Do I have to set/create the new parameter somewhere else before declaring it in my stored prod?

Comment: No - the syntax in the post is correct. Make sure you added a comma after @lang varchar(2) = null (the 1st parameter declaration)

Comment: @gymcode I edited my post so you should just be able to copy and paste it into SQL management studio and execute it. Can you try this? It should work...

Answer (score 2):

Adding the parameter is simple, I've used place holders as we don't know what you want to call the param or what datatype it is.

All you need to do is add the parameter in the `ALTER` statement.

```
ALTER procedure [Config].[usp_ListBusinessUnit] 
@lang varchar(2) = null,
@newParamName newParamType -- Your new stuff
as
-- the rest of your stored proc here
```

Now don't forget to do something with the new parameter in the stored proc.

Comment: I received the error `Incorrect syntax near '@hideInactiveCompany'.`. Do I have to set/create the new parameter somewhere else before declaring it in my stored prod?

Comment: Note the comma after the first parameter. Parameters are effectively a comma separated list.